# How to convert FITS pixel coordinates to ra and dec

Tags: astropy, astronomy, fits

I have a FITS image with no headers except NAXIS. It is an image of M52 cluster. I know the image is centered on the cluster, and given the image is 2000x2000, I guess the x,y position 1000,1000 corresponds to ra=351.2deg, dec=61.5933deg.
I have used DAOStarFinder to find other sources in the image. That returns a set of sources each with an xcentroid and ycentroid component. Is it possible to convert those xcentroid and ycentroid values into ra/dec values?

Thank you,
Paul

Comment: Please show us your code :)

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow") Please be aware this is not a code-writing or tutoring service. We can help solve specific, technical problems, not open-ended requests for code or advice. Please edit your question to show what you have tried so far, and what specific problem you need help with. See the [How To Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask "How To Ask a Good Question") page for details on how to best help us help you.